# car Battery charger (3.3V)

Tags: automotive, amperage, 3.3v

I have a project in mind, but i'm stuck.

I want to power a board (which works on 3.3V, 13/16 mah on reception and 37 mah on emission) with a battery from a car light adapter.

It seems that standard batteries are at 3.6/3.7V and not at 37mah at all.

So i have some questions:
1) Is it a bad thing if a battery is at 40 mah or higher ?
2) How can I design a card to regulate the voltage from 12V (car lighter) to 3.3V and still have the amperage I need (if it's needed). I read the LM317 could help, but it seems not because of the amperage.
3) The board needs to be supplied a day or so, is it possible with that amperage ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "mAh" is a measure of capacity. "mA" is a measure of current.

Answer (score 1):

Supplying more current than required is not a problem; a circuit will only use what it needs. Personally I recommend a switching buck regulator for its higher efficiency, which will also make your board last longer on the same supply. Check the datasheet of the chip in question for a usable schematic and selectors for the other parts (capacitors, diode, inductors, etc.). Also note that automotive power can jump as high as 14V at times, so don't be afraid to overspec a little bit.

Comment: Oh ok, so i can take more.
I think i'll take one of these http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/696752758/26650_LiFePo4_Cell_Rechargeable_Battery_3.html?s=p
2300 mah, it will last ~62 hours cause of the 37 ma.

Comment: Careful with LiFePO though, you can't use the (exact) same charger as LiPo.